# How to calculate N-Grams

Tags: n-gram

I encounter a problem when trying to figure out how n-grams is calculated.

I am wondering that when calculating n-grams(not the frequency), can the positions of common elements be exchanged ?

These are several examples:

(assume that extra symbol is added at the beginning and the end)

1.

```
%Gorbachev%

%Gorbechyov%
```

should the v_ be considered as a common element ?

2.

```
%grew%

%ewgr%
```

should gr and ew both be considered as common elements ?

3.

```
%gladstone%

%astone%
```

should it start from the e% or start from the %a ?

Comment: Did you check Wikipedia first for [approximate matching with n-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram#n-grams_for_approximate_matching) and [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)?

Comment: @Aurélien Yes, I did check Wiki, but I still have some problems, I am thinking that a few examples may clear things out... and I am also wondering if I am doing a 3-gram, should I add 2 %s at the beginning and the end ?